# PHPWORD: I can't set property 'paragraphStyle' in textrun

Tags: php, phpword

This works

```
$text = $textrun->addText($organization['name']);   
$text->setFontStyle($textFontStyleBold);
$text->setParagraphStyle($textParagraphStyle);
```

but...

```
 $textrun = $section->createTextRun();
 $textrun->setParagraphStyle($textParagraphStyle); 

 $text = $textrun->addText($organization['name']);   
 $text->setFontStyle($textFontStyleBold);
 $text->setParagraphStyle($textParagraphStyle);

 $text = $textrun->addText(", bla_bla");
 $text->setFontStyle($textFontStyle);
$text->setParagraphStyle($textParagraphStyle);

// var_dump ($textrun)
// protected 'paragraphStyle' => null
```

Answer (score 0):

$textrun = $section->createTextRun($textParagraphStyle);